# How to update a list of items fetched from a DB, using Server Actions, without a page refresh?

Tags: forms, next.js, server-action, next.js14

I have a list of items fetched from my db.
I want to create a form which adds one item to the db using Server Actions and updates the list without the page refreshing.

[image: my goal]

My current "solution" is, inside my Server Action, using `revalidatePath(path)` after adding the item to the db, but this refreshes the page.